# What type of exception does rescue => e captures?

Tags: ruby, exception, try-catch

In Ruby, you can capture exceptions using `rescue => e`, without explicitly passing any type of exception such as `rescue CustomException => e`.

I can tell it doesn't capture every exception, because:

```
def foo
  foo
rescue => e
  puts "It never reaches this block"
end

foo
```

This infinite loop never gets captured, and it raises a `SystemStackError`.

What type of exception does `rescue => e` captures?

Comment: in ```rescue => e```, why "e"?

Comment: @TPR `e` is the name of the variable that stores the exception instance. It could be any other name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't specify an exception filter, [the implicit default is `StandardError` (scroll down to the bulleted list of default exceptions, it lists the defaults for both `rescue` and `raise`)](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Exception.html). This also applies to the trailing "inline" `rescue` modifier, whose syntax doesn't allow to specify an exception filter at all:

```
foo rescue bar
# always implicitly rescues StandardError
```

Not all [`Exception`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Exception.html)s inherit from [`StandardError`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/StandardError.html), so this will not rescue *all* exceptions, but it will rescue all that can be sensibly rescued. Exceptions that don't inherit from `StandardError` are usually ones that are *so* severe or that point to a problem inside the execution engine, that user code cannot recover from them in a sensible way. For example, an out-of-memory-error or an internal error inside the VM.

[`SystemStackError`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/SystemStackError.html) is an example of an exception that doesn't really make sense to handle in user code. If the stack is exhausted, you cannot make any more method calls, but it is pretty much impossible to do anything in Ruby *at all* without making a method call. Plus, a stack overflow is usually a programming error, you need to fix the error, not the symptom.

Note that such a "catch-all" exception handling is usually frowned upon. You should be as narrow as possible in your exception specification and maybe even examine the exception object inside your `rescue` block to make sure that the exception you got is really the one you want to handle. Very broad catch-all exception specifications have the risk that you will rescue exceptions that you don't know how to handle.

Comment: in ```rescue => e```, why "e"?

Comment: You would have to ask the person who wrote the code.

Comment: sorry because the textbook I read also wrote "e"